# Como gerar variaveis sequenciais (ex: d1, d2, d3) e depois juntar tudo em uma unica variavel PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Tenho script usando foreach que gera as variaveis $d, $m, que recebem o valor de uma consulta mysql e coloca esse valor no input

```
echo "
<input type='text' name='tipo' value='".$d."'>
<input type='text' name='metragem' value='".$m."'>
";
```

Aí queria que cada campo fosse unico, pois a consulta retorna varias linhas, para isso adicionei $n

```
$n = 0;
foreach($unidades as $unidade){
    $n++
    echo "
        <input type='text' name='tipo".$n."' value='".$d."'>
        <input type='text' name='metragem' value='".$m."'>
    ";
}
```

até ai tudo bem, mas preciso agora juntar todos em um unica variaval $dtotal e $mtotal, ex:

```
$mtotal = 'tipo'.$n1.'|'.'tipo'.$n.'|'.'tipo'.$n(quantos n tiverem);
```

Comment: *"queria que cada campo fosse unico"*, mas qual a razão para isso, identificar no `javascript`? Se for, melhor seria definir o id e não o name único. Usando o mesmo name (`tipo[]`) você consegue pegar um array de valores e facilmente juntar fazendo um `foreach`, tem vários exemplo aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Leandro, pode responder pra gente se você precisar "juntar" os campos na hora que está montando a página, pra exibir o total, ou quando você postar a página, dai ler todos os campos e juntar pra somar o valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver seu problema, criando o `$mtotal` e `$dtotal` dentro do seu próprio foreach, assim:

```
$n = 0;
$mtotal = ''; // inicializa a variável mtotal
foreach($unidades as $unidade){
    $n++
    echo "
        <input type='text' name='tipo".$n."' value='".$d."'>
        <input type='text' name='metragem' value='".$m."'>
    ";

    //concatena a variável existente com o formato desejado
    $mtotal .= 'tipo'.$n.'|';

}
```

Fazendo do mesmo jeito pro `$dtotal`, que você não deu o exemplo de como ficaria.

Comment: David, perfeita sua ideia se for pra exibir o total que já existe no banco, mas e se for pra juntar na hora depois de um post? Eu fiz um comentário nesse sentido, mas lendo sua pergunta fiquei com dúvida, seria legal o @leandro-marzullo responder isso

Comment: Entendi sua dúvida, é uma questão válida a ser vista com o Leandro Marzullo

Comment: Deixei um comentário na pergunta.. pelo exemplo que ele deu `$mtotal = 'tipo'.$n1.'|'.'tipo'.$n.'|'.'tipo'.$n(quantos n tiverem);` me parece que quer juntar mesmo na hora de montar a página, do jeito que está na sua resposta

Comment: é isso mesmo @DavidAlves, valeeew!!